# How can we stop the comments from being an area for arguments?

Tags: discussion

The comments section has recently become an area where disagreements are voiced and the exchanges have detracted from the answers to the posters questions and often go far astray from the context of the original question. Can we start a practice where if you disagree with an answer down vote it and leave a single comment as to why. I am guilty of getting into this in trying to defend my views as have others, but that only serves to degrade the site as it gives the poster the impression that we are not united in our faith.

Comment: *"it gives the poster the impression that we are not united in our faith."* But that's the absolute truth. There are many users on this site I personally cannot recognise as brothers and sisters in Christ, though as most of us here are inquisitive people who care about truth I hope that will one day change.

Comment: @curiousdannii I started to retort to your comment, but realized that I would be perpetuating the very thing I asked about. Our divergent beliefs should not be aired online on this site it is for answering questions about Christianity, and though we are encouraged to answer from our denominational perspectives, we do not need to argue them on the site. We should keep it civil.

Comment: I only commented like that because this is Meta. It's essential that we show our divergent beliefs, but in the questions and answers, not the comments. And of course we should always act civilly, or even more than that, friendly.

Comment: @curiousdannii that can be done without demeaning one another's views, after all Jesus said we should not judge, but that is just what we do when we de mean another's faith. If everyone agreed there would not be so many denominations.

Comment: @both: Discussions in comments on Meta are allowed, even encouraged. That said, yes, please do keep the discussion on topic. :)

Answer (score 5):

Before saying anything else, let's take a look at the [help center's guidance on comments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When should I comment?**
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).
>
> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an
>     existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or
>     up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

As for what should be done...

- learn the guidelines
- follow the guidelines yourself
- resist the urge to "[just say one thing](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing)"
- If you see an invalid comment, do not argue, do not respond.  Just flag it and let a moderator delete it.

Flagging is the safest course of action.  Far too often, even those of us that should know better get caught up in comment discussions.  The best you can do is to try to avoid doing the same thing yourself, and just flag invalid. non-constructive, incorrect, offensive, or otherwise unwelcome comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a difference between arguing in comments and doing what I sometimes do: point to something in a question or answer that to me appears to be illogical, and ask for a better explanation. I don't think there's a problem with that (though perhaps there is if I forget to explicitly ask for an improvement), but what does the rest of the community think?