# Can we have this "no advice allowed" site disclaimer like judaism.stackexachange has?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion

Take a look at what judaism.stackexchange does.

[image: What it do baby. It's the ice-man Paul Wall.]

Similar to our site, I bet they were getting inundated with "advice" questions and finally put this disclaimer up there with helpful links. Why don't we do that?

Comment: [Here's the post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3883/9917) where this was implemented on Judaism.SE.  It looks like SE staff has to implement it.

Comment: Note that general advice questions aren't off topic on J.SE. That notice is meant to head-off questions asking for _personalized, professional_ advice such as Jewish legal rulings about what a person should do according to _halakha_ in a given specific scenario. Also: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29305805#29305805

Comment: Also: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29307613#29307613

Answer (score 8):

I like the idea.  It doesn't seem to prevent other notices, like community ads, from appearing in the sidebar; rather it just shifts everything down a bit.

Let me suggest that we use the following wording, adapted from Judaism.SE's example and [Jon Ericson's relevant post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1601/21576):

> Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but *does not offer personalized advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6018/21576).

Feedback and edits welcome.

Comment: I wonder if [this question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4241/6071) would be better to link to. The question is worse but the answers are much better... Maybe we can edit the question to be better.

Comment: The question I linked to is focused more on outsiders, whereas the one you're linking to is focused on debating and implementing a policy. To explain why we don't allow pastoral care questions, the first type of question would be better I think.

Comment: @curiousdannii I see your point.  At the very least we could link to the top answer.  Or, we could put together a canonical post that brings together all three answers to that question into a single new question or question/answer.  The reason I picked that link is because it's the one that's included in the pastoral advice close reason, which probably should be reevaluated as well.

Comment: I've updated the link to use the new FAQ question.

Comment: I've used this answer to create the notice. Hopefully people will take it to heart.

Comment: @Jon You left in Nathaniel's referer code!

Comment: @curiousdannii: Heh. Fixed.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hey, I would have offered to let someone else put their referrer ID in there after I got the gold badge :)